# escalation workflow for overdue task

Tags: workflow

I want to create a workflow, which is update the task status if task is overdue.
Can any body give me some code on this.
Thanks

Comment: I **Partially** got it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56471181/flowable-bpmn-workflow-extend-due-date-in-task-escalation

Answer (score 0):

```
< Task is overdue? > --Yes--> [update task]
```

Comment: Thanks for replay,My problem is if workflow is running,How workflow know the task is overdue?